# Error in extraction of tweets from twitter

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Twitter</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            // set up the click handler for the form button
            var button = document.getElementById("submit");
            button.onclick = getTweets;
        }
         // when you click "Get Tweets" we call this function
        function getTweets() {
            // set up a new XHR request
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // we're calling search.php and passing in a query string
            var url = "search.php?query=";
            var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
            if (!query) {
                query = "html5";
            }
            // we encode the query to handle any special characters properly
            url += encodeURIComponent(query);

            // this is the function that is called when the XHR request
            // to our search.php script is handled, and a response sent back
            xhr.onload = function () {
                // if everything went okay, then send the response data
                // to the displayTweets() function
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    displayTweets(xhr.responseText);
                } else {
                    var errorDiv = document.getElementById("error");
                    errorDiv.innerHTML = "Error getting tweets: " + xhr.status;
                }
            };
            // make the request!
            xhr.open("GET", url);
            xhr.send(null);
        }

        function displayTweets(tweets) {
            // tweets is a big long string, so we need to parse it 
            // into JSON first
            tweets = JSON.parse(tweets);
            var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
            // clear existing tweets from list
            while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
                ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
            }
            // add new tweets
            for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = tweets[i].tweet;
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Query:
        <input type="text" id="query">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Get Tweets">
    </form>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <ul></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

In the above code when I enter some text in the textbox and click on "Get Tweets" button it gives an error as `Error getting tweets: 0`. The search.php when executed independently without embedding in html and javascript gives accurate and required results.Can you please check the html and js code and suggest any changes in code??

Comment: There's a simple way to debug this yourself: open the developer tools (F12) in Chrome or Firefox and open the "Network" tab. There you will see exactly what HTTP request has been made and what was the response. Maybe there's some ID missing or something like this and you are getting a 500 error from the server.

Comment: after debugging it is giving error as "no element found" in search.php.How should I resolve it?

Comment: modify the following lines as
if(xhr.status==200) to if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)

and

xhr.open("GET",url) to xhr.open("GET",url,true)

Comment: inspite of updating the code as per your suggestion its giving error as "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP" on line 40

Comment: I tried the code on localhost i.e I use wamp server then its giving error message as "Error getting tweets: 200" Please experts help me out

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue is CROSS-DOMAIN Ajax issue. When you execute the search.php independently, then there is no X-domain issue. But when you are embedding the code in some html, check if the html is part of the same domain or not. Also, if you are trying to run the html file from file:/// it will not work.

Comment: well I dont have any idea how to check for the cross domain and resolve this respective issue.Can ypu please elaborate?